# What are words like "Hey Man", "Hey you", "Hey Dude" called

Tags: grammar

Is there a term for words that summon someone like "Man," "Dude," "Kid" in sentences such as "Hey, Dude," "Listen up, kid," etc?

I am sure there is, but I can't really remember what it is.

Comment: "Man", "Dude" or "kid" are *pronouns*.  I'm not sure how to interpret the phrase "words that summon someone", because it's actually the entire phrase that summons/commands; "Man"/"Dude"/"kid" are just substitutes for the pronoun "you".

Comment: "Hey Dude / You think you're bad / But she's a sad sack / And you're no better"...  My apologies to any Beatles fans.

Comment: @MT_Head I take serious offence. I darn you to heck!

Comment: Are you thinking of an imperative phrase? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood

Comment: @MT_Head I don't think that man/dude/kid are pronouns.

Comment: @user814064 no no. I wasn't talk about the mood of the sentence, just a term for those words. I think the term is vocative

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you might be thinking of [vocative](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vocative).

> *of a word or word group*: marking the one addressed (as *mother* in “mother, come here”)

Answer (score 4):

Basic grammar may tell you the "Hey" is an "interjection."

When used to specifically address a person (or an audience,) as in your example, the *Hey* there is a "vocative adjunct" with an interpersonal function of addressing between speaker & listener (or writer & reader): "O, Romeo, Romeo …"

> This consists of relatively emotional words or phrases which express an exclamation, a call, a curse, or an oath simply added to the main predication. This vocative adjunct usually begins an utterance. But it can also be placed at the end of an utterance or even between the subject and the predicate. (Dinh-Hoa Nguyen, 1997)

An interesting explanation of the vocative [here](http://grammar.about.com/od/tz/g/vocativeterm.htm).

The [WP entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocative_case#English) has an explanation of the difference between the interjection and the vocative case.